# How to set the concurrency for each queue separately in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, concurrency, queue, sidekiq

Say for example, I have two queues and I want each queue to process only one job simultaneously.

Now I have one queue and I have it something like

```
bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q queue_name
```

I want two queues to process the job simultaneously and each queue should have concurrency 1. So, is that possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Why dont you just start tow sidekiq process one for each queue.This can be unstable though
`bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q first_queue`
`bundle exec sidekiq -c 1 -q second_queue`

Comment: We try not to have more process as we hope each process would consume memory.

Comment: @h0lyalg0rithm why is it unstable to have a process dedicated to a queue?

Answer (score 0):

Queues are just places from where sidekiq takes jobs to perform. Concurrency allows to perform taken jobs simultaneously. I mean queues don't process jobs, they just collect them and determine their priority. Therefore the phrase `set the concurrency for each queue` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I could understand what you mean. As far as my requirement is concerned, I need to take the first job from each queue and process simultaneously. Hope this would make sense. I will update the question, if this is clear.

Comment: Sidekiq executes jobs asynchronously.  You cannot control when they are executed.  Your requirements make no sense in terms of Sidekiq.